# How do you print any printable file in Windows 10 by command line?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, printing, automation

How do you print *any* printable file by command-line in Windows 10?

Images, PDF, text, word documents and such.

This question refers too all files you can print by right-clicking and selecting print from the menu that opens up.

[image: Print option]

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/83142-automatically-print-files-placed-in-folder

Comment: Sorry, we don't do software recommendations here. Try over on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ and expand on your use case a bit.

Comment: @Karu, you are right. I misworded my question. I basically wanted a way to make Windows print every document that is dropped in a specific directory. I guessed it should be 'simple' but apparently it is not as common a use case as I thought!
I will rephrase my question!

Comment: @GloriaGu Thank you! This is actually relevant. Have an ice day. Note for future users: the useful answers are somewhere down in the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 8):

PowerShell can print any file, using the same action as the Print verb
defined for the file-type.

The PowerShell command to use is
[Start-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1),
and the idea is simply to invoke the file itself with the Print verb.

The syntax is very simple:

```
Start-Process "path-to-file" -Verb print
```

I tested it with a PDF file, and the file printed correctly.

A more elaborate example is to be found in the documentation:

> **Example 2: Print a text file**
>
> This example starts a process that prints the C:\PS-Test\MyFile.txt file.
>
> ```
> Start-Process -FilePath "myfile.txt" -WorkingDirectory "C:\PS-Test" -Verb Print
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A few file extension specific solutions:

To print an image file:

```
mspaint /p some_file.png
```

This prints pdf files:
[Print pdf files with command line](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Eem36/pdftoprinter.html)

Comment: This only handles PDFs and images, and thus does not properly answer the OP.